# php7.0 + nginx makes 404 page error

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404

In AWS EC2 Instance, I make web environment using php7.0 and nginx.
And this makes 404 page error.

HTML Extension page is work well, but not on php.

in default.conf

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;

#charset koi8-r;
#access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

location / {
    root   /var/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
}

#error_page  404              /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /var/error;
}

# proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
#}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    root    /var/www;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
#    deny  all;
#}
```

}

in fastcgi_params

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

and in nginx.conf

```
    user  www-data;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Whole environment is Nginx + php7.0 + mariaDB on AWS EC2 Instance.

I can't find what is wrong...

Comment: Oh my mistake. contents of fastcgi_param is
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

Comment: fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks! I edit the fastcgi_params part.

Comment: So where exactly is `index.php` located?

Comment: at the /var/www directory. if there is index.html that is at the same area where index.php, 404 page not found error doesn't occur..

Comment: Ok, I guess I am confused as to why you are asking php7 to look for `/var/www/index.php` at `/scripts/index.php`

Comment: would you please say in other words? I can't understand what you say... forgive my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post this as an answer, but I am unfamiliar with php7 and AWS EC2.

You seem to have an inconsistency in your `nginx` configuration.

This block:

```
location / {
    root   /var/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
}
```

tells `nginx` that your files are located below `/var/www`, so that, for example:

- the URI `/index.html` can be found at `/var/www/index.html`
- the URI `/foo/bar.html` can be found at `/var/www/foo/bar.html`

The `index` directive tells `nginx` to look for `index.php` (etc.), also below `/var/www`. However, any URI ending with `.php` is processed by a different location block.

The block:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    root    /var/www;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

is intended to process `.php` URIs. Now, unless your architecture is special, the SCRIPT_FILENAME parameter passes the location of the file from `nginx` to the `php` subsystem. And on most systems, the value of `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name` is used which means that:

- the URI `/index.php` can be found at `/var/www/index.php`
- the URI `/foo/bar.php` can be found at `/var/www/foo/bar.php`

Assuming that `root` is set to `/var/www`.

---

In your configuration file, you are setting `root` in the `location ~ \.php$` block **but not using it**. The `root` directive sets the value of `$document_root`.

There are other issues, but the important one is that (unless you are using a special architecture) the value of SCRIPT_FILENAME should be:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

You should place `include fastcgi_params;` **before** any `fastcgi_param` directive to avoid the included file silently overwriting the desired value.